# Add function data to my model - Node/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post, mongoose

I have a form with the input fields "firstName", "lastName" and "assetTag". I want to submit that form and post all that data plus one additional field called "modelType". The data from the modelType field is from the function call **si.system()** but i'm not sure how to pass that into the Model because it's a promise.

How can I pass the data from my console.log(data.model) into my formData?

app.js post request:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {

        si.system()
    .then(data => console.log(data.model))
    .catch(error => console.error(error))

  const formData = {
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    assetTag: parseInt(req.body.assetTag)
  }

  const system = new System(formData);

  system.save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

});
```

Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

var SystemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    assetTag: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    modelType: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('System', SystemSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about getting that value out of the promise you need to look into [async / await](https://javascript.info/async-await).

here's the code

```js
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {

  let data = await si.system();

  const formData = {
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    modelType: data.model,
    assetTag: parseInt(req.body.assetTag)
  }

  const system = new System(formData);

  system.save()
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

});
```